# Replacing the first set of numbers in a string in R tidyverse

Tags: r, parsing, dplyr, tidyverse, rename

I am using R tidyverse and trying to parse the first set of numbers after some characters in a column name. I want to keep the characters and the second set of numbers but remove the first set of numbers. For example, in the df below, we have "var1_1975" and "var1_1976". After the transformation, these variables should be named "var_75" and "var_76".
I am trying this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame("var1_1975" = c(1:5), 
          "var1_1976" = c(3,2,1,1,1),
          "age" = c(25,41,39,60,36) ,
          "satisfaction" = c(5,3,2,5,4)
          )

#  Output
# var1_1975 var1_1976 age satisfaction
# 1         1         3  25            5
# 2         2         2  41            3
# 3         3         1  39            2
# 4         4         1  60            5
# 5         5         1  36            4


cols <- df%>% 
select(c(1:2)) %>% #select some cols by index
names() #retain only the col names

df <- df %>% 
  rename_with(.fn = ~ gsub("\\d+", "", .x, fixed = F),
          .cols=contains("var") & ( contains("1975") | contains("1976")   ) ) %>%
  rename_with( .fn = function(.x){paste0(.x,  "_",
                                     parse_number(gsub("var1_","",cols)) -1900)},
           .cols=(contains("var")  ))  #add year as suffix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different approaches that you could use for this problem; one potential solution is to use a regex to match the first 'set' of digits that you want to remove, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame("var1_1975" = c(1:5), 
                 "var1_1976" = c(3,2,1,1,1),
                 "age" = c(25,41,39,60,36) ,
                 "satisfaction" = c(5,3,2,5,4)
)

df %>%
  rename_with(~gsub("([^\\d]+)\\d+_(\\d{2})(.*)", "\\1_\\3", .x))
#>   var_75 var_76 age satisfaction
#> 1      1      3  25            5
#> 2      2      2  41            3
#> 3      3      1  39            2
#> 4      4      1  60            5
#> 5      5      1  36            4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Explanation:

```
pattern = "([^\\d]+)\\d+_(\\d{2})(.*)"
1st capture group: "([^\\d]+)" match anything that's not a digit
don't capture: "\\d+_" match any digits before the underscore
2nd capture group: "(\\d{2})" match exactly two digits (i.e. 19)
3rd capture group: "(\\d+)" match any remaining digits (i.e. 75 or 76)

replacement = "\\1_\\3"
print the first and third captured groups, separated by an underscore
```

Comment: also I added tidyverse as a library to the question, so you can remove it if you want!

Comment: Thanks very much. I realized that my actual use case was slightly different that what I described, and so I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76911026/parsing-column-names-with-characters-and-numbers-in-r-tidyverse

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
rename_with(df, ~str_replace(.x, "\\d_\\d{2}", "_"), contains("var"))
```

Output:

```
  var_75 var_76 age satisfaction
1      1      3  25            5
2      2      2  41            3
3      3      1  39            2
4      4      1  60            5
5      5      1  36            4
```