# Parsing column names with characters and numbers in R tidyverse

Tags: r, parsing, tidyverse, rename

*** Edited
I am using R tidyverse and trying to parse specific column names as follows:
The column names in question contain characters and a number (representing a year), like "var 1975", "var 1976", etc.
I would like to parse these names as to become: "var_75", "var_76", etc.
In other words, I want to parse the number representing the year and remove the first two digits, then add the year as two digits to the characters, separated by an underscore.

I am trying this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble("var 1975" = c(1:5), 
          "var 1976" = c(3,2,1,1,1),
          "age" = c(25,41,39,60,36) ,
          "satisfaction" = c(5,3,2,5,4)
          )

#  Output
# var 1975 var 1976   age        satisfaction
# 1         1         25            5
# 2         2         41            3
# 3         3         39            2
# 4         4         60            5
# 5         5         36            4



df <- df %>% 
   rename_with( .fn = function(.x){paste0(.x,  "_",
                                     parse_number(cols) -1900)},
           .cols=(contains("var")  )) %>%  #add year as suffix
   rename_with(.fn = ~gsub("([^\\d]+)\\d+_(\\d+)", "\\1_\\2", .x),
          .cols=contains("var"))
```

Comment: why are you posting the same question again ?

Comment: I realized that my actual use case was slightly different that what I described, and so I posted this as a new question. The reason is that my variables are named differently and I also need to parse the year from the numeric part of the variable name.
Is it better to edit the original question after having received a valid response?

Comment: re:*Is it better to edit the original question after having received a valid response?* - uh I'm honestly not sure! I guess it depends on if you think the question is distinct enough, and/or both questions are likely to be useful into the future (i.e. will anyone stumble upon your first question via Google)

Comment: It's worth noting that your data frame is not tidy because your column names contain information (the year).  The tidyverse is, unsurprisingly, designed to work with tidy data.  So when you feed it untidy data, you are more likely to cause yourself pain at some point in your workflow.  Here, a tidy data frame would be "long"  and contain columns similar to Age, Year, Value and Satisfaction, where Value contains the value in the corresponding year_xx column.  An ID variable would probably be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rename_with(df, ~ str_replace(., " \\d{2}", "_"), contains("var"))
```

---

*Explanation*: `" \\d{2}"` is a regex string which looks for a space, followed by two digits. It's replaced by an underscore.

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  var_75 var_76   age satisfaction
   <int>  <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
1      1      3    25            5
2      2      2    41            3
3      3      1    39            2
4      4      1    60            5
5      5      1    36            4
```

Answer (score 1):

alternatively please try

```r
df_renamed <- df %>%
  rename_with(~str_replace(., "^var \\d{2}", "var_"), starts_with("var"))

# A tibble: 5 × 4
  var_75 var_76   age satisfaction
   <int>  <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
1      1      3    25            5
2      2      2    41            3
3      3      1    39            2
4      4      1    60            5
5      5      1    36            4
```